# Tracing CPU cycle with Pintool?

Tags: profiling, intel, intel-pin, cpu-cycles

I am trying to run SPEC17 benchmark using Pintool. While doing so I need to log CPU cycle and memory address accessed. Pintool have pinatrace tool to log memory addresses but I can not find anything to log CPU cycles. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: PIN's JIT dynamic binary instrumentation adds overhead, especially if you're tracing *every* memory access.  Even if it does have a way to collect timestamps, it might be significantly different from an uninstrumented run.  (Not just a constant factor slower everywhere).  It's not going to be even close to the timing of a real CPU running uninstrumented code.  Are you sure you want to use PIN, not hardware performance counters like `perf record` or something, maybe with intel-pt?

Comment: Your best bet would be to find a tool that models CPU cycles based on the instructions you ran. Try looking at SDE, it might have this capability.